# Innerclass sharing attribute information

Tags: java, java-7

I have a class called **ContentStream**... the problem is that the inner class **AddRectancle** suppose to get the info of the **getter** of the class **GraphicBeginn**...I thought the class **ContentStream** can reach the getter at least as the getter is public ... plse tell me how to

```
public class ContentStreamExt extends ContentStreamProcessor

{

private Matrix  graphicalMatrix;

public ContentStreamProcessorExt(ExtListener extListener)
{
    super(extListener);
}

private void enhanceAdditional()
{
    GraphicBeginn beginnGraphic = new GraphicBeginn();

    super.register("a", beginnGraphic);
    super.register("b", new AddRectangle(beginnGraphic));
}

private static class AddRectangle(GrapicBeginn beginn)
{
    // should get the info of uUx and uUy 
}

private static class GraphicBeginn implements ContentOperator
{
    private float   uUx;
    private float   uUy;

    public float getuUx()
    {
        return this.uUx;
    }

    public float getuUy()
    {
        return this.uUy;
    }
..... // the input for uUx and uuy will be created in a method 
}
```

Comment: I already instanciated an object of GraphicBeginn as I was hoping to get the uUx and uUy there and just pass it to AddRectangle(float x,float y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you gave has a number of problems, it doesn't compile correctly as another poster has noted. It also appears you are providing a method signature while also declaring a class called "AddRectange". Is this a class or a method? You need to decide which, it can't be both. Here is an example that I think illustrates what you're trying to do in a general sense:

```
public class SampleClass {

public SampleClass() {
}

private void sampleClassMethod() {
    A a = new A();
    a.acceptB(new B());
}

private class A {
    public void acceptB(B bObject) {
        System.out.println(bObject.memberVar1);
    }

}

private class B {
    private int memberVar1 = 5;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, The add rectangle class should be passed an instance of graphic begin on which it can invoke the public getters. This wiring can be done by the content stream class.

By the way the following is syntactically invalid

```
private static class AddRectangle(GrapicBeginn beginn)
```

Comment: ok... but the content stream class can't read the getter of the GraphicBeginn class even its  public

Comment: Where are you trying to do that? What are the available methods on beginnGraphic instance in the enhanceAdditional method?

Comment: there is just one private method in graphhicBegin filling uUx and uUy.... in the method enhanceAdditional() I tried to ...GraphicBeginn beginnGraphic = new GraphicBeginn();... float x = beginnGraphic.getuUx; float y = beginnGraphic.getuUy; and then pass it into AddRectangle(float x,float y)

Comment: Please correct the attached code in the question; it wouldn't compile as is because of the syntax problem highlighted in this answer. Then write the code that you wish to achieve, highlighting with a comment the part where you get the compilation error.